# Google chrome: how to display full text when the mouse hovers over a table cell

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, overflow

**Expected behavior**

I have a table on my web page. In some table cells, it has long text and I set these css for td label. When the text is longer than the table cell's width, it will be hidden.

```
td {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

When the mouse hovers over these table cells,i want the full text appear.

**Current behavior**

**For safari**, when the mouse hovers over the table cell who has long text, the full text appears.
[image]

**For google chrome**, there is no reaction when the mouse hovers over it. 
[image]
**Question**

How google chrome can display the full text like safari? Any suggestions or ideas will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case, it is better to put "title" attributes in your `<td>`.
[More about Title Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp%20Title%20Attributes)

For Example :

```
<td title='Full Text about School 1'>School 1 Data</td>
<td title='Full Text about School 2'>School 2 Data</td>
...
<td title='Full Text about School X'>School X Data</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use title attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

```html
<p>Newlines in title should be taken into account, like this <abbr title="This is a
multiline title">example</abbr>.</p>
```